# Prevent (jquery ui) datapicker from flipping to current month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the latest jquery (2.0.3) and jquery ui (v1.10.3). Here are my settings to initialize datepicker:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: 40,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
    },
});
```

As you can tell I display two months for datepicker. When I select date in current month everything is fine.

But when I select a date in a second month the selected date is moved to the first one (because of updated state?). I dont want this behaviour, I just want selected date in second month. Is it possible to disable this refresh state?

Edit:
Just to avoid confusion I need an inline datepicker (the one that when you select a date does not disappear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`onClose`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) function to check if the selected date is on the same month of the start date.

If not you can set the option [`showCurrentAtPos`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showCurrentAtPos) to 1, so you'll datepicker will show the current selected date as the second date picker.

Quick ref:

> When displaying multiple months via the numberOfMonths option, the
>   showCurrentAtPos option defines which position to display the current
>   month in.

Code:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [2, 1],
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: 40,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
    },
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        var now = new Date()
        if (now.getMonth() == inst.selectedMonth) {
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'showCurrentAtPos', 0);
        } else {
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'showCurrentAtPos', 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/UqHYV/

Comment: thanks for your help but my datepicker is inline which means is always open when you select a date and this solution does not work

Comment: Using inline at the moment I can't find any workaround (it's a bit buggy with multiple month display)

Comment: This bug is 3 years old :( I may think that a key to solve this problem is not to use minDate at all but use a custom parameter that adds class "ui-state-disabled" to all <td> so it behaves like minDate but does not flip months